# Thymeleaf's Spring th:errors not working as described in documentation

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

When working with Thymeleaf in combination with Spring you are provided with some extras like the `th:errors` attribute. According to the [documentation here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/thymeleafspring.html#field-errors) it should be possible to access field error messages like this:

```java
<input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('datePlanted')}" th:errors="*{datePlanted}">Incorrect date</p>
```

So for my application I adopted this piece of code for password input:

```java
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" th:field="*{password}"/>
<p class="error-message" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password')} ? _ : 'hidden'"
                         th:errors="*{password}">Invalid password</p>
```

Since I don't want the error-message paragraph to get canceled out during preprocessing I `th:classappend` hidden depending on an existing error. This way I can utilize the paragraph via JavaScript by the front end.

Unfortunately, although I followed the documentation 1:1 the paragraph gets deleted when there is no error. It seems that the `th:errors` attribute somehow implements a `th:if` as well, which looks for an existing error and if none is found it will not show the paragraph at all.

In the documentation's example code the condition whether the parapgraph is displayed is explicitly specified via `th:if` attribute. Therefore this behavior is not comprehensible for me.

**Is this a bug, a feature or is it simply me?**

Comment: I have not used `th:errors`, I usually do this: `th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#fields.errors('password'), ', ')}"`. One other thing you can try is replacing the `_` in your `th:classappend` with just an empty string (`''`) to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, this would work as long as there is at least one error inside `#fields.errors`. If not, it would output an empty string overriding the standard value which I want to be in place in case no errors are reported by the backend so the fontend could use it. Similar to your solution I currently use `th:text="${#fields.hasErrors('password')} ? ${#fields.errors('password')[0]} : #{password-reset.password.error}"`. Anyhow, although this works, it still leaves me confused about the `th:errors` attribute.